# Problem with 3D python scipy data interpolation - axis swapped on result data

Tags: python, scipy, 3d, plotly, interpolation

I have encountered a problem **interpolating 3D scattered scalar data** in python with scipy.
I have a lots of 3d-points *p*-List (3D Tupels) and a corresponding *PHI*-List (Potential).

For computing the gradient vector on each point, I am using the numpy.gradient function, which needs a gridded data structure. **I have encountered an error with the gridded data.**

I am generating the grid via:

```
grid_x, grid_y, grid_z = np.mgrid[-maxabsx:maxabsx:40j, -maxabsy:maxabsy:40j, -maxabsz:maxabsz:40j]
grid_z1 = griddata(p, PHI, (grid_x, grid_y,grid_z), method='linear')
```

Whilest checking the data, I found out, that the **gridded 3D data does not match with the original PHI data**. It seems like the values on the x- and z-axis are kind of swapped.

In the following picture you see a mesh with colored dots ***on*** and inside the mesh. This is the original data. You can see, that the color fades from red to blue from positive to negative x.

The gridded data however seems to fade from red to blue from positive z to negative z. It seems like the data has swapped from x to z. (I removed all 'nan' data points in the grid outside the convex hull of the mesh.)

[3D-Data picture - original vs. gridded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPP9x.png)

I have no clue what may cause this data swapping and I dont think it is because of an error in plotting.
I am plotting the data via plotly the following way:

```
## Draw original Phi points
data.append(go.Scatter3d(
    x=p[:,0],
    y=p[:,1],
    z=p[:,2],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=3,
        color=PHI,                # set color to an array/list of desired values
        colorscale='Portland',   # choose a colorscale
        opacity=.5,
        colorbar=dict(thickness=40),
        cmax=max(PHI),
        cmin=min(PHI)
    )
))

## Draw interpolated gridded phi data
data.append(go.Scatter3d(
    x=gx_flat[toDisplay],
    y=gy_flat[toDisplay],
    z=gz_flat[toDisplay],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=2,
        color=grid_phi_flat[toDisplay],                # set color to an array/list of desired values
        colorscale='Portland',   # choose a colorscale
        opacity=.7,
        colorbar=dict(thickness=40),
        cmax=max(grid_phi_flat),
        cmin=min(grid_phi_flat)
    )
))
```

If anybody has an Idea where this error in interpolation comes, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `np.meshgrid` has an `indexing` parameter, `xy` vs `ij`.  Default is `xy`.  But `mgrid` uses the `ij` convention.  Read `meshgrid` docs to see if the explanation fits your case.

Comment: Genius! It worked! I actually just switched from np.mgrid to np.meshgrid and it automatically worked. Thanks very much!